# How to run a function asynchronous in with RGtk2

Tags: r, user-interface, asynchronous, gtk

As the title implies I would like to be able to run a function asynchronous in a GUI created with RGtk2.

The function in itself is an R wrapper for a system command, thus the bulk of the processing time is used on a system() call, and the processing time can range from 10 min to an hour. I would like the GUI to still be responsive in that period.

As it is now the function is put in a gSignalConnect(GtkButton, 'clicked') and the rest of the GUI is thus unresponsive until the 'clicked' signal is terminated.

Does anyone have an idea regarding whether this is possible?

best
Thomas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There might be a more direct way, but I think you can do this with `gTimeoutAdd`:

```
library(RGtk2)

w <- gtkWindow()
g <- gtkVBox(); w$add(g)
b1 <- gtkButton("Start timer"); g$packStart(b1)
b2 <- gtkButton("click me"); g$packStart(b2)


gSignalConnect(b1, "clicked", function(...) {
  id <- gTimeoutAdd(1, function(...) {
    Sys.sleep(5)                        # replace me
    message("Okay, I'm up")
    FALSE                               # one shot
  })
})
gSignalConnect(b2, "clicked", function(...) message('clicked me'))
```

Answer (score 1):

What might work (although not tested, and I am not too familiar with RGtk so no guarantees) is to use the `wait=FALSE` option in the `system` call. The system call is then executed asynchronously. In your gtk GUI you would then have to periodically check if your system call has finished. I believe it is possible using RGtk to have a function using that is periodically called (from the [documentation of RGtk](http://www.omegahat.org/RGtk/Docs/overview.pdf) this is probably `gtkTimeoutAdd()`).

Comment: I thought about this but I would still need a function running in the background, checking for completion, so I was effectively left with the same problem... Plus `wait=FALSE` has caused problems on some systems from time to time. `gtkTimeoutAdd()` was the missing piece.